# CORBA IIOPNet and OmniORBpy, remote method call with valuetype param issue

Tags: .net, python, corba, iiop

My scope: I'm trying to create a CORBA solution for two apps one at .NET side (server) and the other on python (client). I'm using IIOPNet for server and IDLs generation and OmniORBpy for Stubs generations and client calls. In general is working for simple calls like the typical example: Adder. But when a i try to call a method with a custom class it doesn't work.

I have this class on server side(my Remove Object) to be called from the client :

```
public class MyRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool DoSomething(InterfaceRequest requestData)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The input param class type is declared like this on server side (quite simple):

```
[Serializable]    
public class InterfaceRequest
{
    public int SiteId;
    public int UserId;
}
```

I generate my IDLs using CLSIDLGenerator and later my python stubs like "omniidl -bpython -CPython ...", until here everything is OK.

So i start the server (VS debug environment) and now on my client code i resolve the service name, i narrow my remote object successfully and i create my request object but when i try to do this:

```
request = InterfaceRequest()
request.SiteId = 1
request.UserId = 3

result = remoteObj.DoSomething(request)
```

Python blows up with no warning, no exception, any message of any kind, (i updated trace label on my omniORB config file to the highest [40] but nothing is getting traced), it simply crashes, i have tried a lot of stuff and i get always same result. The problem is related to the param of course (i guess).

I'm running the client side like this: 
**python client.py -ORBInitRef NameService=corbaname::localhost:8087**

(My last approach: python object reference architecture and conforming value type param passed by value are not matching at some point)

Tech details: **NET 4.0, IIOPNet (last), Python 2.6, omniORB-4.1.5, omniORBpy-3.5.**

Every help is appreciated, i'm little stuck with this, Thanks.

---

Yes the IDL generated for MyRemoteObject is this one:
.....

```
module module1 {
module module2 {
module module3 {
module module4 {

interface MyRemoteObject {

boolean TestConnection(in double value) 
raises (::Ch::Elca::Iiop::GenericUserException);

bool DoSomenthing(in ::module1::module2::module3::InterfaceRequest requestData) 
raises (::Ch::Elca::Iiop::GenericUserException);
};
```

.....

But now that you mentioned this, i just noticed that on that very same file (myRemoteObject.idl) i have a structure representing the InterfaceRequest type but empty like this:

```
module module1 {
module module2 {
module module3 {

valuetype InterfaceRequest;

};
};
};
```

And of course i generate that IDL somewhere else with the right content:

```
valuetype InterfaceRequest {
public long SiteId;
public long UserId;
};
```

Weird, maybe is the order in which i'm generating this stuff, is that important?, obviously there is something wrong here right?

Finally my python stubs for these couple of classes (remote and parameter type) looks like this:

```
class _objref_MyRemoteObject (CORBA.Object):
    _NP_RepositoryId = MyRemoteObject._NP_RepositoryId

    def __init__(self):
        CORBA.Object.__init__(self)

    def TestConnection(self, *args):
        return _omnipy.invoke(self, "TestConnection", _0_module1.module2.module3.module4.MyRemoteObject._d_TestConnection, args)

    def DoSomething(self, *args):
        return _omnipy.invoke(self, "DoSomething", _0_module1.module2.module3.module4.MyRemoteObject._d_DoSomething, args)

    __methods__ = ["TestConnection", "DoSomething"] + CORBA.Object.__methods__
```

And the InterfaceRequest:

```
class InterfaceRequest (_0_CORBA.ValueBase):
    _NP_RepositoryId = "IDL:module1/module2/module3/InterfaceRequest:1.0"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            if len(args) != 2:
                raise TypeError("InterfaceRequest() takes 2 arguments "
                                "(%d given)" % len(args))
            self.SiteId = args[0]
            self.UserId = args[1]
        if kwargs:
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

So even if the IDLs are not quite right (just guessing) at the end the python stubs are getting generated with the right content and right paths.

Thanks for the help (i have changed real names, hope id doesn't matter) and sorry about so large post.

Comment: Is there an ´interface MyRemoteObject´ in IDLs? You need to implement IDL interface like: "public class MyRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject, moduleIDL.module2.MyRemoteObject".

Comment: I have updated the post with the IDLs and Stubs generated. Thanks, i work with Windows 7 64 bits, just in case this could be a problem (but i doubt it because everything else is working except this type of calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forgot to add the interface stub, generated by IDLCompiler.

```
public class MyRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject, module1.module2.module3.MyRemoteObject
{
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool DoSomething(InterfaceRequest requestData)
    {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

You need to implement the valuetype in C# using these rules bellow:
[It's not your error now, but you gonna get this error soon or later].

- you did implement a class XYZImpl, where XYZ is the type name of the valuetype
- XYZImpl inherits from the abstract class XYZ (this class is generated by the IDLToCLSgenerator)
- XYZImpl is in the same namespace as XYZ
- XYZImpl is serializable
- XYZImpl has a parameterless public constructor
- XYZImpl is not abstract
- XYZImpl implements all the inherited abstract methods and properties 
  [Link](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Just remembering, you need to open an IIOPServerChannel doing:

```
int port = 0;
IiopChannel chan = new IiopChannel(port);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);
```

Comment: I really don't understand why i have to inherits back from the interfaces i got generated from my classes in first place, i'm missing part of the workflow here, anyways i created an empty interface for my InterfaceRequest class now called InterfaceRequestImpl on NET side manually and IT WORKS!!!. However would you mind to explain me what do you do with the dll generated by IDLToCLSCompiler.exe, do you include it as reference in your project and inherit all the types from their corresponding interfaces?, looks like ugly process to me i rather prefer to do it manually as long as i can. Thanks.

Comment: It's not ugly. IDLs is a contracts, like your service API. Supose you won´t  to change it every time.

Comment: The InterfaceRequest is your valuetype, you don't need to create an hypothetical interface. Just create a class with name InterfaceRequestImpl and inherits from the abstract class InterfaceRequest (from dll generated in IDLToCLSCompiler.exe).If we didn´t have these rules to mount a valuetype, the ORB couldn't find the class to instantiate. It's the way that IIOP.NET has to find your implementation. [hard to write in a few words :-) ]